# Invalid SQL identifier - org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.ParseException: Encountered "TABLE" at line 2, column 16

Tags: sql, python-3.x, apache-flink, flink-sql, pyflink

I am trying to run a PyFlink Job that takes data from source Kafka topic sinks it into hdfs. There is a weird SQL-related error that keeps arising. This is from SQL statement in Apache-Flink (PyFlink) Table API Sink:

**SQL:**

```
sql_statement_sink = """
            CREATE TABLE avro_sink (
                timeTime STRING,
                correlationId STRING,
                spanId STRING,
                appName STRING,
                messageType STRING,
                message STRING,
                tag STRING,
                journey as SPLIT_INDEX(tag, '_', 2)
            ) PARTITIONED BY (
                journey,
                appName,
                messageType
            ) WITH (
                'connector' = 'filesystem',
                'partition.default-name' = 'others',
                'format" = 'avro',
                'path' = 'file:///Users/ahmedawny/PycharmProjects/ms_log_consumer/output'
            ) 
        """
```

**Full Error:**

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner (file:/Users/ahmedawny/PycharmProjects/%20ms_log_consumer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyflink/lib/flink-dist_2.11-1.14.0.jar) to field java.util.Properties.serialVersionUID
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.flink.api.java.ClosureCleaner
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "log_consumer.py", line 96, in <module>
    main(**vars(args))
  File "log_consumer.py", line 77, in main
    statement_set.add_insert(avro_sink, table_known_tag)
  File "/Users/ahmedawny/PycharmProjects/ ms_log_consumer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyflink/table/statement_set.py", line 116, in add_insert
    self._j_statement_set.addInsert(target_path_or_descriptor, table._j_table, overwrite)
  File "/Users/ahmedawny/PycharmProjects/ ms_log_consumer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1285, in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
  File "/Users/ahmedawny/PycharmProjects/ ms_log_consumer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyflink/util/exceptions.py", line 146, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/Users/ahmedawny/PycharmProjects/ ms_log_consumer/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
    raise Py4JJavaError(
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o697.addInsert.
: org.apache.flink.table.api.SqlParserException: Invalid SQL identifier 
            CREATE TABLE avro_sink (
                timeTime STRING,
                correlationId STRING,
                spanId STRING,
                appName STRING,
                messageType STRING,
                message STRING,
                tag STRING,
                journey as SPLIT_INDEX(tag, '_', 2)
            ) PARTITIONED BY (
                journey,
                appName,
                messageType
            ) WITH (
                'connector' = 'filesystem',
                'partition.default-name' = 'others',
                'format" = 'avro',
                'path' = 'file:///Users/ahmedawny/PycharmProjects/ms_log_consumer/output'
            ) 
        .
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.parse.CalciteParser.parseIdentifier(CalciteParser.java:96)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.ParserImpl.parseIdentifier(ParserImpl.java:109)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.StatementSetImpl.addInsert(StatementSetImpl.java:76)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.bridge.java.internal.StreamStatementSetImpl.addInsert(StreamStatementSetImpl.java:48)
        at org.apache.flink.table.api.bridge.java.internal.StreamStatementSetImpl.addInsert(StreamStatementSetImpl.java:28)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.ParseException: Encountered "TABLE" at line 2, column 20.
Was expecting one of:
    <EOF> 
    "." ...
    
        at org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.FlinkSqlParserImpl.generateParseException(FlinkSqlParserImpl.java:40981)
        at org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.FlinkSqlParserImpl.jj_consume_token(FlinkSqlParserImpl.java:40792)
        at org.apache.flink.sql.parser.impl.FlinkSqlParserImpl.TableApiIdentifier(FlinkSqlParserImpl.java:6316)
        at org.apache.flink.table.planner.parse.CalciteParser.parseIdentifier(CalciteParser.java:87)
        ... 15 more
```

Thanks in advance.

Adding more sentences as StackOverflow is not allowing to post with "mostly code".
Adding more sentences as StackOverflow is not allowing to post with "mostly code".Adding more sentences as StackOverflow is not allowing to post with "mostly code".Adding more sentences as StackOverflow is not allowing to post with "mostly code".Adding more sentences as StackOverflow is not allowing to post with "mostly code".Adding more sentences as StackOverflow is not allowing to post with "mostly code".Adding more sentences as StackOverflow is not allowing to post with "mostly code".

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error at `journey` field and change it to `journey String`. using `SPLIT_INDEX` function when you insert data to the sink.

Comment: I did that, that's not the case. Now it gives an error on "as" coming after "STRING". It doesn't like it

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
sql_statement_sink = """
            CREATE TABLE avro_sink (
                timeTime STRING,
                correlationId STRING,
                spanId STRING,
                appName STRING,
                messageType STRING,
                message STRING,
                tag STRING
            ) WITH (
                'connector' = 'filesystem',
                'partition.default-name' = 'others',
                'format" = 'avro',
                'path' = 'file:///Users/ahmedawny/PycharmProjects/ms_log_consumer/output'
            ) 
        """
```